# AngularJS Ng-repeat вывод поля

Tags: angularjs

```
<div ng-repeat="inf in type.info">
  {{ inf.name}}
  {{ inf.lastname}}
</div>
```

Дело в том, что в `inf.file` может храниться 1 или 2 названия файла(file или file file2), и хотелось бы их вывести по отдельности. Если файла 2, то они разделены пробелом. Реально ли как-то их вывести по такой конструкции?

```
<div ng-repeat="inf in type.info">
      {{ inf.name}}
      {{ inf.lastname}}
      <div ng-repeat="file in inf.file">
       <a href="">{{file}}</a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: `ng-repeat="file in inf.file.split(' ')"`

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!